# Can I set datasouce = null from clientside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I have a checkbox list in VB.NET. On page_load it will bind some data from the sql datasource.

But, I want to make this checkbox list's datasource=nothing from the client side on focus event of the text box.

Can i do this? If yes, then how?

Comment: You cannot do this client-side. What you can do is clear out all the items in the list box with js if that is what you are trying to do. If you truly want to remove the datasource you need to do that with a postback. As far as the client-side operations are concerned, there is no such thing as a Datasource unless you have some ajax calls set up to the codebehind

Comment: I do like this to hide the list.
 function filterModule() {    
                    $(".filtercheckbox td").each(function() {
                    $(this).hide();
                });
            }

Comment: but now i try to do 
   chkl1.DataSource = Nothing
   chkl1.DataBind() 
END SUB 
this supposed to clear the checkbox list but there is no effect of this two line of code why?

Comment: Not sure about vb, but in C# I would do `chkl1.DataSource = ""; chkl1.DataBind();`

Comment: So basically you want to delete all the item of check box list, correct ?

Comment: now keep it simple 
i hide all the list from the js 
after that in same form when i provide checkbox list's datasource =nothiing in vb.net and datasource="" in c#  and then END SUB 
this will not clear the check boxlist and display all the previous data in that checkboxlist

Comment: Then instead of hiding the data you can simple remove the children nodes, that will clear the check box data bind.